# Как добавить атрибут свойства в модель из другого проекта?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

Подскажите. Хочу вынести модели данных в отдельный проект. В проекте приложения делаю ссылку на проект с моделями. Также в приложении определяю классы с метаданными основных моделей, где добавляю свойствам различные атрибуты, например Display.
В Startup.cs добавляю в класс модели атрибут ModelMetadataType, который указывает на класс метаданных таким вот образом

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(MyClass), new ModelMetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(MyClassMetadata))).
```

Далее запускаю и ничего не просходит. Атрибуты из классов с метаданными метаданных в свойства классов не добавляются. Как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгого копания выяснилось, что невозможно автоматически добавить атрибуты из одного класса в другой. Для реализации обработки атрибутов нужно реализовывать свой провайдер метаданных и в соответствующих методах изменять метаданные модели.

```
    public class MyMetadataProvider : IDisplayMetadataProvider, IValidationMetadataProvider
    {
        public void CreateDisplayMetadata(DisplayMetadataProviderContext context)
        {
        }

        public void CreateValidationMetadata(ValidationMetadataProviderContext context)
        {
        }
    }
```

В ASP .NET Core MVC нужно добавить свой провайдер в список провайдеров в Startup.cs.

```
services.AddMvc(c=>c.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new MyMetadataProvider()));
```